wilder.nvim - auto-suggestions in ':' cmdline support don't work
I use vim-plug. In my init.vim I have:
" wilder.nvim
runtime ./plugins/configs/wilder.vim

in wilder.vim:
lua << EOF
require("wilder").setup{}
EOF

And in plug.vim
call wilder#setup({'modes': [':', '/', '?']})
call wilder#set_option('renderer', wilder#popupmenu_renderer({
      \ 'pumblend': 20,
      \ }))

The plugin works. When I type :PlugStatus I can see the status 'OK'. Also, the '/' and '?' commands work, but ':' doesn't. There's no suggestion when I type the first letter and I need to hit tab for something to appear, just like it was before installing the plugin.
Looking for a possible solution.

You are looking at the wrong place. Read the plugin's documentation and use the plugin's issue tracker.

@romainl I'm looking where I think I need to look after trying to find a solution for multiple hours. You could try recommending a solution. I can read docs any time, but it doesn't mean I can easily find the right info. That's why stackoverflow was made so that people can communicate and find a solution.

The solution was adding call wilder#setup({'modes': [':', '/', '?']}) in init.vim instead of plug.vim where I store my plugins.

Have you installed romgrk/fzy-lua-native Plugin? This plugin is required by wilder for fuzzy search among commands and files. Try after installing this plugin and use this configuration for fuzzy search:
add these lines in your init.vim
call plug#begin()

Plug 'gelguy/wilder.nvim', { 'do': 'UpdateRemotePlugins' }
Plug 'romgrk/fzy-lua-native', { 'do': 'make' }

call plug#end()

" ++once supported in Nvim 0.4+ and Vim 8.1+
autocmd CmdlineEnter * ++once call s:wilder_init() | call wilder#main#start()

function! s:wilder_init() abort
  call wilder#setup({
    \ 'modes': [':', '/', '?'],
    \ 'next_key': '<Tab>',
    \ 'previous_key': '<S-Tab>',
    \ 'accept_key': '<Down>',
    \ 'reject_key': '<Up>',
    \ 'enable_cmdline_enter': 0,
    \ })

  let s:highlighters = [
    \ wilder#pcre2_highlighter(),
    \ wilder#basic_highlighter(),
    \ ]

  call wilder#set_option('pipeline', wilder#branch(
    \ wilder#cmdline_pipeline({
    \   'fuzzy': 1,
    \   'fuzzy_filter': wilder#lua_fzy_filter(),
    \ }),
    \ wilder#python_search_pipeline(),
    \ ))

  call wilder#set_option('renderer', wilder#popupmenu_renderer(wilder#popupmenu_border_theme({
    \ 'highlights': {
    \   'border': 'Normal',
    \ },
    \ 'border': 'rounded',
    \ 'highlighter': s:highlighters,
    \ 'left': [' ', wilder#popupmenu_devicons()],
    \ 'right': [' ', wilder#popupmenu_scrollbar()],
    \ })))
endfunction


thank you for the recommendation, I'll try it
